# ggplot: object 'DiscreteRange' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is embarrassing. I've been using the `ggplot2` package on a regular basis over the past few months, and now suddenly things seem to go seriously wrong.

Apparently, whenever I try to plot a bar graph I obtain the error:

> Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
>     object 'DiscreteRange' not found

This is the error that results, e.g., when I try to run a code as simple as the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut)) + geom_bar()
```

There is no graphics output, the code stops with the above error message.

If I recall correctly this used to work up to a few days ago, so I suspect that there is some error in an (update of) another package that interferes. Of course, I may also be doing a very stupid mistake that I don't see.

I'm using RStudio version 0.99.467; more information concerning the system and the relevant packages is provided below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.0         lattice_0.20-33     zoo_1.7-11          digest_0.6.8        MASS_7.3-43         grid_3.2.1          plyr_1.8.3          gtable_0.1.2       
[9] magrittr_1.5        scales_0.2.5.9003   stringi_0.5-5       reshape2_1.4.1      proto_0.3-10        blotter_0.9.1666    tools_3.2.1         stringr_1.0.0      
[17] munsell_0.4.2       colorspace_1.2-6    quantstrat_0.9.1669
```

I tried to restart a fresh R session and even rebooted the computer, to no avail.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just to let you know, the code works fine here, I'm using R 3.1.1-

Comment: It also works on my other computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that the problem is with the `scales` package, which is at version: `0.2.5.9003`.  The packages with "four-part" version numbers `x.y.z.wwww` look like development versions to me.  The current CRAN version is 0.2.5:

```
 a1 <- available.packages()
 a1[a1[,"Package"]=="scales","Version"]  ## 0.2.5
```

I don't know how you ended up with a development version (`devtools::install_github("hadley/scales")` would probably do it) but I would `install.packages("scales")` (or the equivalent through the RStudio GUI) to re-install the CRAN version and see if that resolves the problem.

Alternatively, you could try keeping the development version of `scales` and moving to the development version of `ggplot2` (`devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`).

I'm using the development version of `ggplot2` (1.0.1.9003) with the development version of `scales` (0.2.5.9003) and your example works fine.

Comment: Chapeau! I'm officially impressed. Thank you so much! Installing `scales` from CRAN brought my ggplot back to life :-)